# How to set a default inet addr to ethernet card like wlan have?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, linux, raspbian-stretch

First of all, i am sorry i don't know much about networking and i am beginner in linux networking. Please help me with my problem.

I have a Rpi3 and i am configured it as ethernet router from eth0 to eth1 interfaces. I have used USB to Ethernet converter for the eth1 interface. The output of `ifconfig` is shown below.
[image: ethernet router]

I have configured Rpi3 as hotspot and observed the `ifconfig` and it shown below.
[image: wifi]

For ethernet router, eth1 is not assigned with static IP until a device is connected to the eth1 port but for wifi hotspot it is assigned with a static IP even if there is no device connected.

What i am doing wrong. How to get a static IP for eth1 port even if no device is connected?
Is there any way to assign default inet addr to ethernet ports?

Ethernet router configuration bash script is [here](https://dpaste.de/NaTO#L14)

Wifi hotspot configuration bash script is [here](https://dpaste.de/E4WW#L62)

Comment: Do you solved your problem? `/etc/network/interfaces` is deprecated and conflicts with `dhcpcd`. You should not use it.

Comment: I found the solution. we can add a no-link option in the dhcpcd.conf file. this will solve my problem. So ethernet ip will be availed even if the no device is connected.

Comment: Please make your comment/solution an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not annoy us again all the years.

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

add following

```
auto eth1

iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.2.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.2.0
  broadcast 192.168.2.255
  gateway 192.168.2.1
```

This is one of possible ways of adding static ip to new interface

Comment: i am using stretch version of raspbian. I already configured it using dhcpcd.conf. Please see my configuration bash script https://dpaste.de/NaTO#L14 . For configuring it as hotspot, see my hotspot script https://dpaste.de/E4WW

Comment: what is the difference in `interfaces` file and `dhcpcd.conf`. When i set static ip through `dhcpcd.conf`, i won't get IP address for eth1 until a device is connected. But now i disabled `dhcpcd.conf` and use `interfaces` file for setting static IP and now eth1 assigned with IP address even if no device is connected.  What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Can we achieve the same using dhcpcd.conf file?

Comment: yes, you can add into dhcp.config very similar records (instead of interfaces)  interface eth1
       static ip_address=192.168.2.1/24
       static routers=192.168.2.1
       static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1

Comment: Please look my script. I am doing the same in the script. But it does not assign IP address until a device is connected to the port. That's my question friend?